# Where is code patterns placed if i'm use special reserved words

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

If I create file **.html** and then type **doc** and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, I will get standard struct of HTML page (quick snippet).

But, where can I find all reserved words of all templates available for HTML?

I'm using the VSCode 1.14.2.

Comment: Snippets are provided by the editor, so it would depend on which editor you're using.

Comment: Course, i'm using VSCode 1.14.2

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to *enumerate all available snippets*, type `Ctrl+Shift+P` to open the command palette and then type `snippets`.

Comment: There it is empty and there are no descriptions of templates.

Comment: When I type 'snippets' into the command palette, two items appear: `Insert Snippet` and `Preferences: Open User Snippets`. You should see these two, assuming you've opened a file (snippets are tied to specific languages).

Comment: But where is description about word **doc**?

Answer (score 0):

OMG, i found. This is syntax of Emmet. All descriptions there are
[docs.emmet.io](https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/)